# Create a condition when a close breaks a previous high with only lower highs between them

Tags: pine-script

Here's what I'm trying to target:

[image]

As the title says, the previous high must "collide" with a future, higher candle body, "unobstructed" by previous highs (ie, wicks).

Here is what I tried so far:

```
//@version=4
study("High Space Higher Close",overlay=true)

the_high = high
if high > the_high
    the_high := high
higher_close = close > the_high
plotshape(higher_close,size=size.normal,location=location.abovebar,style=shape.triangleup)
space_between = the_high > highest(high,barssince(the_high[-1]))
plotshape(space_between,size=size.normal,location=location.abovebar,style=shape.circle)
```

I think this makes sense to me, but it does not seem to plot any shapes.

Comment: Edited question to provide more verbose description of pattern I am trying to target.

Answer (score 0):

Try "[Donchian Channels](https://www.tradingview.com/scripts/donchianchannels/?solution=43000502253)" default built-in script, and modify it

Something like that

```
//@version=4
study(title="Donchian Channels", shorttitle="DC", overlay=true, resolution="")
length = input(20, minval=1)
// lower = lowest(length)
upper = highest(length)
// basis = avg(upper, lower)
// plot(basis, "Basis", color=#FF6D00)
u = plot(upper, "Upper", color=#2962FF)
// l = plot(lower, "Lower", color=#2962FF)
// fill(u, l, color=color.rgb(33, 150, 243, 95), title="Background")

breaks = upper[1] != upper and upper[1] == upper[2]
plotshape(breaks ? upper[1] : na, style = shape.xcross, location = location.absolute)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for sharing this. Currently this produces false positives... the previous high must "collide" with a future candle body, unobstructed by wicks. Just like the example shown. Your example seems to line up with that often, but very often does not. This is where I am getting messed up. I edited the question title slightly, adding the word "only", to be clear that there can only be lower highs between. Thanks again.